# why is numpy's origin at the upper left, unlike mathematical convention?

Tags: python, numpy

When you do math and you have a matrix, conventionally speaking the matrix has an origin at the bottom left:

[image]

When you use numpy in python, and you have an array, the array has an origin at the top left:

```
a = np.reshape(np.arange(9),(3,3))
a

>> array([[0, 1, 2],
          [3, 4, 5],
          [6, 7, 8]])

a[0,0]
```

this gives you....0

Why is numpy like this, given numpy is supposed to be a package for doing linear operations in python?

Comment: No, that's not the convention for matrices in math. Matrices don't even have an "origin". You're mixing up matrices and (quadrants of) the coordinate plane.

Comment: When you print `a`, you see a string representation of the array, rows and columns, like a table.  A 2d array does not actually have 'top left', 'bottom right' etc. properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your graphic is not of a matrix, it is of a Cartesian coordinate system. As you say, in the Cartesian coordinate system, the first coordinate give the horizontal position, the second coordinate gives the vertical position, and going up the page means the second coordinate increases. The location `(0, 0)` is at the lower left of many graphics, but it can be adjust to be anywhere, since each coordinate may be negative.

In a traditional matrix, however, the first coordinate is the row, or vertical position, and the second is the column, horizontal position. Going up the page means a decreasing first coordinate. Location `(1, 1)` is the upper left corner of any matrix, since each coordinate must be a positive integer. Here is a Wikipedia image [for a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)):

[image]

Numpy follows the matrix convention, especially in its printing, not the Cartesian convention. (To make it even more confusing, there is an additional common convention, used in graphics, but I'll skip that here.)